# Sass (SCSS) - How to Add to Individual Values in a Class

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I want to add 2px to the padding all around an element.  So
`padding: 10px 14px;`
will become
`padding: 14px 18px;`.  How can I achieve this?

Hopefully there is a more elegant solution than (psuedo-code):

```
$horizontal-padding: 10;
$vertical-padding: 14;

.normal-padding {
    padding-top: $vertical-padding;
    padding-right: $horizontal-padding;
    padding-bottom: $vertical-padding;
    padding-left: $horizontal-padding;
}

.extra-padding {
    ($horizontal-padding + 2 + px), ($vertical-padding + 2 + px);
}
```

Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can write that in a lot of ways. A solution similar to your code could be:

```
$vertical-padding: 14px;
$horizontal-padding: 10px;

.normal-padding {
  padding: $vertical-padding $horizontal-padding;
}

.normal-padding {
  $extra: 2px;
  padding: #{$vertical-padding + $extra} #{$horizontal-padding + $extra};
}
```

A more dynamical way (not really useful if you only have these two variations though):

```
@mixin padding($extra : 0) {
  padding: #{14 + $extra}px #{10 + $extra}px;
}

.normal-padding {
  @include padding;
}

.extra-padding {
  @include padding(2);
}
```

You can even change the code above to keep the `$vertical-padding` and `$horizontal-padding` variables. As I said, there are many ways to do it.

Comment: Great!  Yes in the future I may need to make that dimension into a variable so this works perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. You can use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

:root {
  /* declare global variables */
  --padding-x: 10px;
  --padding-y: 10px;
}

.padded {
  padding: var(--padding-y) var(--padding-x);
}

.extra {
  /* redefine variables for `extra` elements */
  --padding-x: 30px;
  --padding-y: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padded"></div>

<div class="padded extra"></div>
```

Comment: This is great!  I had been meaning to look into custom properties and this is a great way to jump in.  Thanks!